# OpenStudio: dll reference can't be added, make sure it's a valid dll or ocx

Tags: c#, dll

Tried adding openstudio_csharp.dll to a project and received the above error.

A suggestion online was to regsvr32 the dll first which I tried and received a similar error saying that it wasn't a valid dll. Also tried from the 64 folder as suggested elsewhere.

openstudio.dll links without issue.

Running windows 10, .net framework 4.6.1, VS 2017

thanks.

Comment: @oerkelens My mistake, meant 4.6.1

Comment: @mjwills Awesome, I deleted it since it appeared unpopular and tired.